# Import Excel Spreadsheet Into SharePoint 2013 TEMPLATE

Tags: excel, templates, sharepoint, import

I have a report that I modify on a regular basis that I pull about every two weeks. I have created a template that has all of the instructions that I must follow to make a SharePoint List of this information.

The report contains about 800 rows of data. Presently I import the data into a new list and modify the views using my List Template as a guide. It would be nice if I could import the spreadsheet directly into the list.

**Using:**
Sharepoint 2013 Standard
Excel 2013 (Home and Business)

**I have already looked into**

---

- Copy/Paste information (Populates into 1st Cell)
- Standard Save As or Import Spreadsheet

**Thoughts**

- Using VBS or Macros to Copy information over
- Using Sharepoint Workflow
- Using AutoHotKey to Copy and Paste All of the Cells over

Comment: What kind of report, reporting service ? What do you do exactly with excel and the sharepoint list ?

Comment: I have to manage upgrades and then modify the information. I have other people that use the upgrade (and are not using sharepoint at the moment.)